# SaveAs2 gives "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says, I'm receiving this error on compile:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWmTT.png

My code:

```
Sub PasteToWord()

  Range("A1").Select

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Dim AppWord As Word.Application

    Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    AppWord.Visible = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell).Copy
    AppWord.Documents.Add
    AppWord.Selection.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    AppWord.SaveAs2 "C:\Docs\MyDoc.pdf", 17

    Set AppWord = Nothing

    AppWord.Quit

  Loop

End Sub
```

The debugger is highlighting `.SaveAs2` as the root of the issue.

I've gone in to Excel VBA's References menu, and made sure both "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" and "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" are checked.

What could be causing the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.SaveAs2` is a method of a document object, not an application object.

Try

```
AppWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "C:\Docs\MyDoc.pdf", 17
```

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. I know this is another question, but now I'm getting "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error", and it's highlighting `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell).Copy` Is this an issue with me using ActiveCell as the range?

Comment: `ActiveCell` is a Range object which is already specific to a sheet. Just refer to it like that.

Comment: @Rory beat me to it :)

Comment: You guys rule! But, sadly, I'm back to another error on the `.SaveAs2` line. This time, the whole line is highlighted, and the error is '4198': Command failed. I thought it was because I was trying to save as PDF, so I changed the line to `.docx", 16`, but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: [Document.SaveAs2 Method - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx)

Comment: That page was super useful. Thank you to both of you. Sorry if I was a pain. Haha.